Modern fantasy book in which a young boy moves to a new town and is granted strange abilities by an old vintage item he got from a weird shop
I believe I read the book in middle school around 6 years ago and, around this time, the second book had just come out.
If I remember correctly, the protagonist was a young boy who just moved to town and found a weird shop that had given him a weird old vintage item. I don't remember what the item could do, but it gave him strange abilities. He also met another girl who could move through walls.
In the second book, the protagonist was a girl who was capable of speaking to animals because of one of the relics she had obtained.
I believe the book covers were purple with gold. Any help would be appreciated!

The protagonist literally changed into a girl? Or the protagonist of the second book was a different person that was a girl?

The protagonist was a different person that was a girl

Did the protagonist of the second book obtain the relic from the same shop as in the first book?
